# Get <option value>'s of TD from web-page

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to parse data from web-page. Code is simple

```
$site = "www.mytable.com/hop/page.sh"
$test = Invoke-WebRequest $site -UseDefaultCredentials
```

I need to get the hosts data from an option input TD. HTML code looks like this:

```
    <TD WIDTH="40%" VALIGN=TOP>
  <FORM METHOD="POST" NAME=selectionform ACTION="/hop/page.sh">
    <TABLE SUMMARY="Selection table" BORDER=0 WIDTH="100%">
        <TR><TD WIDTH="100%" VALIGN=TOP>
            <TABLE SUMMARY="Maintenance input" BORDER=0>
              <TR><TH ALIGN=LEFT>Hosts</TH><TH ALIGN=LEFT>Tests</TH><TH>&nbsp;<TH></TR>
              <TR>
                 <TD WIDTH="50%" ALIGN=LEFT>
                        <SELECT MULTIPLE NAME=hostname SIZE=15 onChange="updateOptions(window.document.selectionform.hostname.options[selectedIndex].text);">
                           <option value="TEXT">TEXT</option>
    <option value="TEXT1">TEXT1</option>
    <option value="TEXT2">TEXT2</option>
    <option value="TEXT3">TEXT3</option>
                                       ....</TD>
```

How can I get all of these option values using `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code you have tried and describe how it is or is not working for you.

Comment: There's nothing to edit. I'm trying to pase html content of a web-page. And I want to know what method I should use to capture <option value> of <TD>-tag. ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("option") gives a lot of junk by itself.

Comment: And there's no any table or other elements ID's. So I cannot use getElementById()

Answer (score 0):

Nwm, got it myself. To target  without any ID I used `$_.innerText` parameter.

```
$TD = $test.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("TD") | Where {$_.innerText -like "*mytext*"} | select -first 1
```

Worked for me.